# Iterate through multiple dataframes (csv), add a new column and assign a value drived from original dataframe names in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a list of dataframes in .xyz and .csv extension. I tried iterating the .xyz (e.g.apalachicola_mile_76.xyz) extension and .csv files by applying the function;

`split_func`

that splits and take a unique value from the file name then copy it into a new column. However, it gives an error: "There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)".

can only work with one data frame each at a time

```
# Load needed packages
library(tibble)
library(plyr) 
library(readr)

filez <- list.files('.', full.names = T, pattern = '*.xyz')
# create a function to assign values 

split_func <- function(mylist, df){
  split_first <- unlist(strsplit(mylist, '_mile_'))[2] #split the dataframe name,select a value
  split_sec <- unlist(strsplit(split_first, '\\.'))[1] 
  conv_num <- as.numeric(split_sec) #turn the selcted value to a number (integer)
  add_column(df, RM = conv_num) # create new column and add the number
  
}

#iterate the function over each csv file

# first read the exported data
filez_df <- list.files('.', full.names = T, pattern = '.csv') #import exported data 

#apply split_func function to all files

for(i in 1:length(filez_df)){ # iterate through the length of the file
  df_holder <- vector(mode = 'list', length = length(filez_df)) # create an empty list
  df_holder[i] <- split_func(filez[i], read.csv(filez_df[i])) # apply the function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get paths to all .csv files in working dir
csvs <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
xyzs <- list.files(pattern = ".xyz")

# Empty list to hold the result of each iteration
all_files <- list()

for(i in 1:length(csvs)){
  temp <- read.csv(csvs[i])
  mile_num <- sub(pattern = ".*_(\\d{+}).xyz", replacement = "\\1", x = xyzs[i])
  temp$mile <- mile_num
  all_files[[i]] <- temp
}

# Convert list of dataframes to a single dataframe
do.call(rbind, all_files)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. What i wnat to do is that i want to iterate through two different files. one a csv, the other an .xyz extension. The .xyz extension dataframe is saved like this; apalachicola_mile_76.xyz, apalachicola_mile_77.xyz etc.   I have used a function to extract '76' , '77' from the .xyz files. The function (split_func) is expected to create a new column in the .csv file and populate the values for each. I now want iterate through multiple files and apply this function.

Comment: Is each .xyz is paired with a single .csv?

Comment: yes they are paired. each .csv was created from .xyz

Comment: Ok gotcha. In that case, take a look at my updated answer. Does this do what you were expecting?

Comment: Thank you so much. you just saved a life. it worked perfectly. I changed the "f" to "i" in the `all_files[[f]] <- temp`. Maybe you can update it there to help someone else. Also i do not really understand this line of code `sub(pattern = ".*_(\\d{+}).xyz", replacement = "\\1", x = xyzs[i])`. could you explain to me. or help with a comment?  Thanks

Comment: `sub()` extracts the digits from the name of the 'ith' xyz file (like `split_func`) using a regex pattern `.*_(\\d{+}).xyz`. There are lots of resources online about regex; I highly recommend adding it to your toolkit. A related note: my code pairs each xyz with a csv based on the order they appear in `csvs` and `xyzs`. If for some reason they are not in the correct order, they may not be paired together correctly. Is there any useful information in the name of the csv that could be used to match with the xyz? That might be safer than simply iterating through the results of `list.files()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Now i understand the work flow of the code. I really do appreciate. And yes they are paring correctly I have checked several files to be sure. For the purpose of clarity, I exported all the  **.csv** file from the initial **.xyz** with the following code, `lapply(seq_along(list), function(i) { write.csv(list[[i]], sprintf("%02d.csv", i), row.names = F) })` , after reading each with `read.table()`. The files exported with names 01.csv, 02.csv etc. So file name is _01.csv_, _02.csv_ etc.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!